# Vmware Site Recovery Manager Bubble network with SQL Server

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, sql-server-2012

We are trying to test an application that uses sql server 2012 in a bubble network with vmware site recovery manager. This means when we test the replication the servers are on a vlan that can't connect to anything but themselves. One of the services is throwing a sql error

The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context

if I understand the issue the sql server has a SPN registered in Active Directory, which we don't have access to in the bubble network. IS there a way I can change the authentication method or something else where I can get past this error. Everything I see is related to Active Directory which I can't seem to get around.

Comment: Why don't you add a clone of one your domain controllers in the test as well?

Comment: currently our AD servers are still physical servers, we are looking at doing a p2v conversion on them, but right now this isn't an easy fix

Comment: Instead of P2V, you can install an additional domain controller on a VM. It's really quick and easy. If you don't want your clients to use it, just move it in a site with not subnets associated and with a high cost site link to an existing site.. After that, you can use a clone of that VM.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer is to have a clone of one of your AD servers included in the bubble network.. I needed to do this when testing with several applications.

Comment: Thanks we are looking into doing this, but since they are physical servers right now we are looking into creating a read only domain controller that we can use